# Working with large (+15 gb) CSV datasets and Pandas/XGBoost

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, xgboost, dask

I am trying to find a means of starting to work with very large CSV files in Pandas, ultimately to be able to do some machine learning with XGBoost.

I am torn between using mySQL or some sqllite framework to manage chunks of my data; my issue is in the machine learning aspect of it later on, and in loading in chunks at a time to train the model.

My other thought was to use `Dask`, which is built of off Pandas, but also has XGBoost functionality.

I'm not sure what the best starting point is and was hoping to ask for an opinion! I am leaning towards `Dask` but I have not used it yet.

Comment: 15GB is nothing. Spin up sqlite and you'll be set.

Comment: It's more or less 4 x 15 - 18 GB in total - but thanks for the suggestion, I don't know much about 'big data' yet.

Comment: An example of dask with xgboost and csv data that you might find interesting: http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/03/28/dask-xgboost

Answer (score 5):

[This blogpost](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/03/28/dask-xgboost) goes through an example using XGBoost on a large CSV dataset.  However it did so by using a distributed cluster with enough RAM to fit the entire dataset in memory at once.  While many dask.dataframe operations can operate in small space I don't think that XGBoost training is likely to be one of them.  XGBoost seems to operate best when all data is available all the time.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? Why XGBoost isn't one of them? Why XGBoost operates better on the whole dataset available? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I would load your data into an hdf5 file using [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/). This library let's you store data on disk but access it like a numpy array. Therefore you are no longer constrained by memory for your dataset.

For the XGBoost part, I would use the sklearn API and pass in the h5py object as the `X` value. I recommend the sklearn API since it accepts numpy like arrays for input which should let h5py objects work. Make sure to use a small value for `subsample` otherwise you'll likely run out of memory fast.